# Moodle PHP filehandeling

Tags: file-upload, editor, moodle

My problem is that we have made an block that opens a page witha a mform on it. And we use the editor element to start the tinyMCE editor, on the page. But when we save the output, the images oploaded to the text field is only viewable to the admin (the person who uploaded it) and in the mdl_files it sets it to be a draft file. I have been through the documentation, and i might have lost the context on the new page, but im not sure.

Answer (score 2):

In Moodle, files uploaded to a form (either to a filemanager element or a text editor) are stored in a temporary 'draft' area while the form is being edited.

This is so that the actual files are not changed until the form is submitted (e.g. if an admin changed the image embedded in some text, deleting the original, you do not want anyone viewing the page during the editing to see a broken image link).

When working with files embedded in a text editor in Moodle, you need to make sure you copy all existing files into the 'draft' area before you show the form, then copy the 'draft' images into the real area, after the form is submitted.

See https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms#editor for details about how to do this.

Please also note that your plugin will also need a PLUGINTYPE_PLUGINNAME_pluginfile() function in its lib.php, in order to authenticate any file requests from the user's browser and return the file contents. See any of the core activities for examples of this (e.g. mod/data/lib.php - function data_pluginfile()).